# Is an HTML image in an email rendered before or after the recipient receives it?

Tags: html, image, informatica

I have a task to send an email containing an HTML image to recipients without using the internet (SMTP is okay). I need to do this in informatica BDM using a Java transformation. I have the code working with a hyperlink reference to the image but when I try to locally access the picture via absolute path, the image is not added (seems to be an Informatica issue).

My question is:
if I use the hyperlink to point to the image will my server try to add the picture before sending the email, or will the picture be rendered by the clients machine when they receive the email containing HTML?

Here is what my code looks like

```java
 emailDescription = emailDescription + "<center><img \" src=\""+ path + "\" alt=\"Logo\" align=\"middle\" title=\"Logo\"></center><br>";
```

where `path` is just a variable containing a link to the image

Comment: An image in an email is rendered by the email client, but the image can either be fetched from an URL or embedded in the email. If you don't have a web server to serve the image from an URL, you should look for embedding techniques (which unfortunately I don't know).

Comment: @MickaëlBucas thank you for this information. If you'd like to make it an answer I will happily accept it as it provides me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image in an email is rendered by the email client, but the image can either be fetched from an URL or embedded in the email. If you don't have a web server to serve the image from an URL, you should look for embedding techniques (which unfortunately I don't know).

A quick search for embedding images showed me that various email client behave differently, mostly to protect receivers from spam and malicious images or links. You may have to test with some clients used by your target audience.